# Format string to date

Tags: php

I am having difficulty formatting a string to a human-readable date format.

I have:

> 07122012

and need to get

> 7 Dec 2012

Tried:

```
date("j M Y", strtotime($str));
```

Comment: What version of php do you have?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$str = "07122012";
$stryear = substr($str,-4);
$strmonth = substr($str,2,2);
$strday = substr($str,0,2);

echo date("j M Y", strtotime($stryear.'-'.$strmonth.'-'.$strday));
```

it will do the trick, but the best thing is to read the php documentation (probably there is a built in feature)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) (available with PHP >= 5.3.0) like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('jmY', '07122012');
echo $date->format('d M Y') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant way, since you cannot parse this string directly, is this:

```
$date = "07122012";

// parse the dte fist correctly
$parsed_date = date_parse_from_format('dmY', $date);


// Make time, print date
echo date("j M Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $parsed_date['month'], $parsed_date['day'], $parsed_date['year']));
```